# VS2010 MSTest CruiseControl.NET .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, visual-studio-2010, cruisecontrol.net, mstest

We're in the process of upgrading from VS2008 to VS2010 since it's now released. We are using CC.NET along with MSTest and want to use MS coverage tool instead of NCover. Interestingly, as I've seen others talking about as well, when you upgrade your project from VS2008 to VS2010 your Test Projects get converted to .NET 4. Nice move!! So WTF does one do with their CI environment in order to build this stuff (some projects in .net 3.5, some in .net 4 - these are different FRAMEWORKS!) LOL!!!

It seems that I might need to have my CC.NET build two separate projects? - not sure about how to run the units tests from cruise with .net 4.

Has anyone done this and have a snippet of their config they might share? And I thought this was going to be a simple thing. :(

thanks!
Bill44077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer yet - VS2010 SP1 Beta allows you to create MSTest projects in .net 3.5 instead of 4.0. Interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Lots of information about doing MsTests from ccnet:

[make ccnet self test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003741/make-ccnet-self-test)

Also there's a [/tv switch on msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383985.aspx) to have it use the 3.5 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you or not but we successfully build multiple frameworks at the same time in the same cc.net project by using the devenv command. If you point it at the VS 2010 com file it sorts out which frameworks to build.

http://ccnet.sourceforge.net/CCNET/Visual%20Studio%20Task.html