# make ccnet self test

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

i want to run a test project in ccnet,
can anyone help?

---

i am not using NUnit. I am using [Test Class()] attribute in my web project, and wanna run this project from ccnet

Comment: What unit testing framework does this project use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the test framework would be [MsTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243147(VS.80).aspx)

In order to run MsTest on the build server you [have to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689025/running-mstest-in-cruise-control-net-build-server) install visual studio or do a work around or [hack](http://www.shunra.com/shunrablog/index.php/2009/04/23/running-mstest-without-visual-studio/) (alternate [hack](http://mindinthewater.blogspot.com/2008/11/executing-visual-studio-unit-tests.html)).

Then you can use [MsTest.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx)

[Here is the official documentation on running MSTest tests.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182469.aspx)

[Similar question and more hacks or work-arounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261290/how-do-i-use-mstest-without-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using NUnit, you may want to take a look at [the documentation](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Using+CruiseControl.NET+with+NUnit)

Comment: hi Rob van,
i am not using NUnit.
I am using [Test Class()] attribute in my web project,
and wanna run this project from ccnet

Comment: @sag: Please add this information to your original question. I'm afraid I'm not that familiar with testing web projects to help you out, but others may.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking in CCNet to run a msbuild task
There are a number of examples to run MSTest from MSBuild tasks.

This one looks prommesing:
http://harriyott.com/2005/07/running-mstest-from-msbuild.aspx?post=/2005/07/running-mstest-from-msbuild.blogpost

--
I myself am using NUnit and xUnit. Might you consider switching to NUnit for testing? There is a wider adoption of NUnit in combination with CCNet, which makes searching answers easier.